# css3 viewport height does not seem to work on ipad

Tags: css, ipad, viewport-units

If I set a div with to

```
height:85vh;
```

the bottom of the element id off the screen by quite some amount (the for the page is only about 40px high....)

To get it to fit on the page I have to set it to

```
height:55vh;
```

Also this only works in portrait mode, if I turn the ipad to landscape it still seems to think the viewport is portrait even if I refresh the screen!

Setting vh to 85 works on android tablets, windows tablets, and desktop browsers (android and windows tablets also resize the viewport on rotating the device). Why is ipad acting so odd?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue now too, and I guess the temporary fix until it is fully supported, would be a Javascript hack. Check the viewport height with Javascript, and use it to set the height of the elements. On tablets, there will be 2 viewport heights, one for each orientation, so I would do a recalculate when changing the orientation.

A good guide can be found here: http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change